# Getting TypeError: Cannot set property 'scripts' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, typeerror

I have the following AngularJS code:

HTML:

`<input type="text" class="form-control" id="repoInput" style="margin: 10px 0 10px 0"
                                       placeholder="Stored Procedures"
                                       ng-model="procedureInput"
                                       uib-typeahead="key for key in getScripts(selected.branchClone, selected.type) | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:10"
                                       typeahead-on-select='addStoredProcedure($item, selected);procedureInput = "";'
                                       typeahead-loading="templateLoading"
                                       typeahead-wait-ms="100" />`

```
$scope.getScripts = function (repo, template) {
items.then(function (payload) {
            $scope.repos[template] = template;
            $scope.repos[template][repo] = repo;
            console.log($scope.repos[template]);
            console.log(repo);
            console.log($scope.repos[template][repo]);
            $scope.repos[template][repo]["scripts"] = payload.data.value;
            deferred.resolve(payload.data.value
                .map(function (x) {
                    return x["path"];
                }));
        });
}
```

I do have values for `template` variable and `repo` variable. But, still, I am getting an error on

`$scope.repos[template][repo]["scripts"] = payload.data.value;` saying

**TypeError: Cannot set property 'scripts' of undefined**

Comment: Show the code where repo is defined. That likely holds the key.

Comment: sry, just updated my question.

Comment: What does the console.log output? Is repo an object?

Comment: What is the type of repo? It seems it's an object, that can't be stored inside of a map structure.

Comment: For 3 console log statements, I am getting following outputs: Database, master, undefined. So as you can see, I am getting the value of repo but still getting undefined for `console.log($scope.repos[template][repo]);`

Comment: Post a sample of data for `$scope.repos` and a sample call to `$scope.getScripts`

Comment: @lealceldeiro `$scope.repos` looks like `{ template: { repo: { "": "" } } }` and I have added html to the question for `$scope.getScripts` call.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to revisit how you are using bracket notation. I think you are probably looking for `$scope.repos[‘template’] = template` and something similar for your role assignment. What is the shape of the data stored in `template` and `role`?